# Spring roo sorting table coumns

Tags: sorting, spring-roo

How do I customise Spring roo generated screen with tables to implement sorting on click of column name ?

Thanks, 
Amber

Answer (score 1):

Spring Roo doesn't includes features about that, you must customize table generation (tagx files) to include your own tables.

Another way is to use gvNIX 1.2.0 (with Spring Roo 1.2.4) that includes the Dandelion-Datatables add-on which let you to change default tables to jQuery Datatables. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/QuickStartGvnix